# Stuck with problem set 3 plurality. Check50 tells that something wrong, but when i tested it myself, nothing went wrong

Tags: c++, cs50

Now I have been studying the cs50 online course. I have solved this problem and stuck with the 
plurality problem for a week. And this is the result when the check50 check my code.
How can I get out of this mistake which I don't know what it is because when I test it myself, nothing went wrong?

[This is what check50 showed to me.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LUriQ.png)

```
#include <cs50.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

// Max number of candidates
#define MAX 9

// Candidates have name and vote count
typedef struct
{
    string name;
    int votes;
}
candidate;


// Number of candidates
int candidate_count;

// Array of candidates
candidate candidates[MAX];

// Function prototypes
void merge(int left, int mid, int right);
void merge_sort(int left, int right);
bool vote(string name);
void print_winner(void);

int main(int argc, string argv[])
{
    // Check for invalid usage
    if (argc < 2)
    {
        printf("Usage: plurality [candidate ...]\n");
        return 1;
    }

    // Populate array of candidates
    candidate_count = argc - 1;
    if (candidate_count > MAX)
    {
        printf("Maximum number of candidates is %i\n", MAX);
        return 2;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < candidate_count; i++)
    {
        candidates[i].name = argv[i + 1];
        candidates[i].votes = 0;
    }

    int voter_count = get_int("Number of voters: ");

    // Loop over all voters
    for (int i = 0; i < voter_count; i++)
    {
        string name = get_string("Vote: ");

        // Check for invalid vote
        if (!vote(name))
        {
            printf("Invalid vote.\n");
        }
    }

    merge_sort(0, candidate_count - 1);

    print_winner();
}

// Update vote totals given a new vote
bool vote(string name)
{
    // TODO
    string name1[candidate_count];
    int votes1[candidate_count];
    for (int i = 0; i < candidate_count; i++)
    {
        name1[i] = candidates[i].name;
    }
        int sum = 0;
    for (int j = 0; j < candidate_count; j++)
    {
        if (strcmp(name, name1[j]) == 0)
        {
            sum = sum + 1;
       }
        else
        {
            sum = sum + 0;
        }
    }

    for (int j = 0; j < candidate_count; j++)
    {
        if (strcmp(name, name1[j]) == 0)
        {
            votes1[j] = candidates[j].votes + 1;
        }
        else
        {
            votes1[j] = candidates[j].votes + 0;
        }
    }
    for (int j = 0; j < candidate_count; j++)
    {
        candidates[j].votes = votes1[j];
    }
    if (sum == 1)
    {
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}

// Print the winner (or winners) of the election
void print_winner(void)
{
    // TODO
    string name2[candidate_count];
    int votes2[candidate_count];
    for (int i = 0; i < candidate_count; i++)
    {
        name2[i] = candidates[i].name;
        votes2[i] = candidates[i].votes;
}

    for (int j = 0; j < candidate_count; j++)
    {
        if (votes2[j] == votes2[candidate_count - 1])
        {
            printf("%s\n", name2[j]);
        }
    }
    return;
}

void merge(int left, int mid, int right)
{

    int len1 = mid - left + 1;
    int len2 = right - mid;
    int i;
    int index1 = 0, index2 = 0;

    int left_array[len1];
    int right_array[len2];
    string strleft_array[len1];
    string strright_array[len2];


    for (i = 0; i < len1; i++)
    {
        left_array[i] = candidates[left + i].votes;
        strleft_array[i] = candidates[left + i].name;
    }
    for (i = 0; i < len2; i++)
    {
        right_array[i] = candidates[mid + 1 + i].votes;
        strright_array[i] = candidates[mid + 1 + i].name;
    }

    i = left;
    while (index1 < len1 && index2 < len2)
    {
        if (left_array[index1] < right_array[index2])
        {
            candidates[i].votes = left_array[index1];
            candidates[i].name = strleft_array[index1];
           index1++;
        }
        else
        {
            candidates[i].votes = right_array[index2];
            candidates[i].name = strright_array[index2];
            index2++;
        }
        i++;
    }

    while (index1 < len1)
    {
        candidates[i].votes = left_array[index1];
        candidates[i].name = strleft_array[index1];
        i++;
        index1++;
    }
    while (index2 < len2)
    {
        candidates[i].votes = right_array[index2];
        candidates[i].name = strright_array[index2];
        i++;
        index2++;
    }
}

void merge_sort(int left, int right)
{
    int mid;
    int i;
    if (left < right)
    {
        mid = (left + right) / 2;
        merge_sort(left, mid);
        merge_sort(mid + 1, right);

        merge(left, mid, right);
    }
}
```

Comment: The spec instructs that "_You should not modify anything else in plurality.c other than the implementations of the vote and print_winner functions_". check50 runs with the distro `main` and the submitted vote and print_winner functions. Therefore `merge_sort(0, candidate_count - 1);` doesn't execute.

Comment: It's work!! Thank you very much. TwT